# Getting an actual return value for a mocked file.read()

Tags: python, tdd, mocking, python-mock

I'm using [python-mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to mock out a file open call. I would like to be able to pass in fake data this way, so I can verify that `read()` is being called as well as using test data without hitting the filesystem on tests.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
file_mock = MagicMock(spec=file)
file_mock.read.return_value = 'test'

with patch('__builtin__.open', create=True) as mock_open:
    mock_open.return_value = file_mock

    with open('x') as f:
        print f.read()
```

The output of this is `<mock.Mock object at 0x8f4aaec>` intead of `'test'` as I would assume. What am I doing wrong in constructing this mock?

Edit:

Looks like this:

```
with open('x') as f:
     f.read()
```

and this:

```
f = open('x')
f.read()
```

are different objects. Using the mock as a context manager makes it return a new `Mock`, whereas calling it directly returns whatever I've defined in `mock_open.return_value`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds like a good use-case for a `StringIO` object that already implements the file interface. Maybe you can make a `file_mock = MagicMock(spec=file, wraps=StringIO('test'))`. Or you could just have your function accept a file-like object and pass it a `StringIO` instead of a real file, avoiding the need for ugly monkey-patching.

Have you looked the mock documentation?

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/compare.html#mocking-the-builtin-open-used-as-a-context-manager

Comment: I tried messing around some with this. It appears that mock_open is return a different object when used in a context manager versus being called directly. I've updated my question. Any ideas?

Comment: I read the top half of that page, but skipped the bottom half for some unknown reason. Herp and derp.

Comment: If the website would be still up to this date, that would be helpful. Now the answer becomes a bit useless.

Comment: Please include imports into your answer as well. Otherwise it is difficult to reproduce

Answer (score 31):

In Python 3 the pattern is simply:

```
>>> import unittest.mock as um
>>> with um.patch('builtins.open', um.mock_open(read_data='test')):
...     with open('/dev/null') as f:
...         print(f.read())
...
test
>>>
```

(Yes, you can even mock /dev/null to return file contents.)

Answer (score 2):

building on @tbc0 answer, to support Python 2 and 3 (multi-version tests are helpful to port 2 to 3):

```
import sys
module_ = "builtins"
module_ = module_ if module_ in sys.modules else '__builtin__'

try:
    import unittest.mock as mock
except (ImportError,) as e:
    import mock 

with mock.patch('%s.open' % module_, mock.mock_open(read_data='test')):
    with open('/dev/null') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Comment: You can use the six library to import `builtins` 

https://six.readthedocs.io/index.html?highlight=builtins#module-six.moves